# Apply CSS for all buttons except a specific ID

Tags: css

I have a code:

```
button {
  background: rgb(1, 81, 227);
  background: linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    rgba(1, 81, 227, 1) 35%,
    rgba(0, 90, 255, 1) 100%
  );
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

And a ton of buttons. I want to apply that css code for all buttons except two, with the IDs startAction & endAction.

How do I do that?

Comment: `button:not(#startAction):not(#endAction)`, probably.

Comment: Can you please post your html code as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`button:not(#startAction):not(#endAction)`

by @underscore_d

Answer (score 0):

Your `startAction` and `endAction` buttons *probably* share some of those styles.

If so, just keep those shared lines within the generic `button` declaration and move the other stuff into a new style and then apply that to the rest of the buttons.

Something like...

```css
button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  ...
}

.fancybutton {
  background: rgb(1, 81, 227);
  background: linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    rgba(1, 81, 227, 1) 35%,
    rgba(0, 90, 255, 1) 100%
  );
  margin: 4px 2px;
  ...
}
```